# QGIS Print Layout - Rotation of Grid Coordinates to match map rotation

Tags: qgis, print-composer, layouts, grids-graticules

I have a layout in QGIS where 3 map views are rotated to 35 deg. The grids automatically rotate to match the maps rotation, however the labels do not.

Does anyone know a way to make the coordinate labels match the rotation of the map?

[image: Grid Coordinates not matching grid/map rotation]

Comment: Which QGIS version are you using specifically? _Layouts_ are used in QGIS 3.x; _Print composer_ is used in QGIS 2.x. Your question title, body and tags include a mixture of these :)

Comment: I don't believe there is a direct option as the `Draw Coordinates` options are based on the item rotation (from those you only have horizontal and vertical options) and not the map rotation. maybe overlaying an empty map on top of the original map that you would rotate the item to the same angle as the original map rotation would do it, but then the labels wouldn't be place on edges of the original map.

Comment: Are these labels generated in the map view or layout view?

Answer (score 1):

Rotation of coordinate values is not possible in QGIS (as of the latest version so far, QGIS 3.12). There are only possible workarounds to get the final look as you want. Both of these mentioned methods require your manual input.

1. Make map rotation as per your requirement. Add grid, set X and Y
   interval as per your need, and enable grid coordinates. Add text
   labels manually for each grid coordinate, write the value of
   coordinate, and rotate the label manually in Item Properties. In the end, remove the coordinates (i.e., disable 'Draw Coordinates') on the grid.
   [image]
2. Export the map as SVG and rotate the coordinate text in an SVG
   editor, e.g., Inkscape.

This idea is good, I would suggest to come ahead and [submit](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues) a feature request to QGIS developers' team.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version, you can click on the 'element properties' of your map, then choose your grid and at the 'grid properties' there's a function "Draw Coordinates". There you'll find an Option 'follow grid rotation". If you activate it, the labels will position themselves according to the grid rotation.
Hope this way it works for you too!

Answer (score 0):

Within the Map Grid Properties -> item properties -> draw coordinates, change the desired grid side (i.e. left, right, top or bottom) from horizontal to "on tick". Make sure follow grid rotation is enabled below as well. From there if you want to slide the coordinate label along the grid tick, you should be able to play with the offsets.